# PHP connected to ORACLE, but can't access table rows

Tags: php, oracle, oracle12c

I have installed PHP and ORACLE on windows 7.

Then I connected PHP  to ORACLE  using PDO, like this:

```
$tns = "(DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 127.0.0.1)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = oradb)
    )
  )";

$db_username = "C##OTO_USER";
$db_password = "oto_user_pass";

try{
    $conn = new PDO('oci:dbname='.$tns.';charset=UTF8',$db_username,$db_password);
}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo ($e->getMessage());
}
```

After connection, I try to query some table:

```
$sth = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM mytable");
$sth->execute();
if ($sth->errorInfo()[2] === NULL) { // if no error, print returned result
    $res = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    var_dump($res);
    
}
else { // if some error, print error message
    echo $sth->errorInfo()[2];
}
```

Strange, is that query returns empty array, as if there is no rows in "mytable", though there are rows,  if run `SELECT * FROM mytable` in `SQL DEVELOPER`, returned all rows.

Also, if make error consciously, then PHP PDO returns error, for example try selecting from non existing table "mytable_bla", gives:

```
OCIStmtExecute: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist (ext\pdo_oci\oci_statement.c:148)
```

So, PDO connected to ORACLE DB, but don't sees rows from table, when actually there are rows in table.

What may be caused this?

**EDIT**

I noticed that PDO don't sees new created table rows, but sees renamed table rows.

For  example `RENAME mytable TO mytable2`, then PDO sees rows from `mytable2`

Comment: Is `===` a typo? (in error handling)

Comment: @mathguy `===` this is php's syntax, for comparing

Comment: OK, got it. I wasn't aware.

Comment: Try a "select count(*) cnt from mytable". That should always return a single row and the value will tell you whether it can see any rows in the table.

Comment: @GaryMyers -- `count(*)` also returns value "0" in PDO, when same `count(*)` returns real count of rows in `SQL DEVELOPER`.

Comment: @OTARIKI - Are you sure that you are using EXACTLY same schema from the same database? Are you using row level security (RLS/ VPD) on  'mytable'?

Answer (score 0):

Try to attach the scheme name to your table name like so:

```
$sth = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM yourSchemeName.mytable");
```